# Set environment variable in /etc/environment file with value containing "#" character

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I am trying to set system-wide environment variable.

I am editing the `/etc/environment` file. I am adding `var="name#12"` inthe file. I log out and log in again for changes to show up.

But `echo $var` gives me `name`.

I have tried escaping `#` with `\` like `var="name\#12"`, but of no use.
Also I tried using `''` instead of `""`.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hash ("#") symbol causes string to be split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688407/hash-symbol-causes-string-to-be-split)

Answer (score 1):

man bash:

```
COMMENTS
       In  a  non-interactive  shell, or an interactive shell in which the interactive_comments option to the shopt
       builtin is enabled (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), a word beginning with #  causes  that  word  and  all
       remaining  characters  on  that  line  to be ignored.  An interactive shell without the interactive_comments
       option enabled does not allow comments.  The interactive_comments option is on  by  default  in  interactive
       shells.
```

create a file myvars.sh in /etc/profile.d/
and add this to file

```
var="name#12"
export var=$var
```

after relogin

```
$ echo $var 
name#12
```

> to disable comments in interactive shell:
>
> ```
> $ shopt -u interactive_comments
> ```

Comment: If I use bash shell,
$ var="name#12"
$ echo $var
name#12

If I declare same in environment file,
$ echo $var
name