# Hash ("#") symbol in /etc/environment causes string to be split

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to add an environment variable to my system via

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

The value is a long string containing a hash, `#`.

With the `#` included, the string is not stored fully; characters after the `#` are gone.

Without the `#` included, the string is stored fully.

I have tried to wrap the string in `" "`:

```
MY_VARIABLE="34534554345 # DFGDGDFG"
```

I expect the variable to be stored fully, like this:

```
34534554345#DFGDGDFG
```

Not this:

```
34534554345
```

Comment: Which shell are you using as with bash and dash I cant reproduce your error with `MY_VARIABLE="34534554345 # DFGDGDFG"`

Comment: If you set your variable to `34534554345 # DFGDGDFG` it will be `34534554345 # DFGDGDFG` and not `34534554345#DFGDGDFG`. Notice the whitespaces.

Comment: @JGNI it's bash

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk it's a django secret key; the spaces are only there to make the # obvious. in reality it's all connected with no white spaces

Answer (score 5):

PAM interprets `/etc/environment`, not a shell. It's intended to be simple `KEY=VALUE` on each line with no need for quotes. `#` marks a comment and there is no way to escape it.

You can use `/etc/profile` to define your environment variable. It should make it available system wide in most cases.

`/etc/environment`

```
TEST2="12345#6789"
```

`/etc/profile`

```
export TEST="12345 #6789"
```

Result:

```
root@tempmon:~ $ env|grep TEST
TEST=12345# 6789
TEST2=12345
```

Comment: I have opened the /etc/profile but where do I put the variable?

Comment: I usually just add them to the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added it to /etc/profile, but it is not included with the list of environment variables printed with "printenv"

Comment: Did you export it? If it is in /etc/profile it needs to be: export VAR="value"